# Cannot find module 'C:\server.js'

Tags: node.js, client, socket.io, npm

I got the following error.I searched and tried something but I couldn't fix the problem.

```
C:\>node server.js

module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
```

My server.js

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

How can I run server.js with node.I have already installed node.js and also typed from command prompt npm install socket.io. Everything seems Ok.
Please help.

Comment: Is the file actually in the directory C:\?

Comment: Did you change your directory `cd <dir>` to where your `server.js` file is?

Comment: @Chad Yes in that directory.

Comment: @ntf I don't believe you, show me the dir command and output.

Comment: @Chad Thank you I have already solved the problem.

Comment: @ntf How did you solve it? I'm getting this mysterious error, when I enter `node server.js;` (note semicolon) in the correct directory C:\Users\<me>\Projects\<project>\ which contains `server.js`. Otherwise `node server.js` (without semicolon) is fine.

Comment: Nvm that was my own fault; the semicolon was causing it to look for a module called `server.js;` which of course doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

You probably didn't save the `server.js` file in `C:`. Use `cd <dir>` to get into the correct directory, then try that node command again.